# problem with if else loop for a month and days problem

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

why do I get the wrong output for the code below, I've put the output below

(some might suggest using date-time module, I'm going with this method due to some complications with the main program)

```
    months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    for month in months:
        if month == {1,3,5,7,9,11}:
            days= 31
            print(days)
        elif month == {4,6,8,10,12}:
            days = 30
            print(days)
        else :
            days = 28
            print(days)
```

I get this output

```
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
    28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question approach

You are checking if an integer is equal to a set. You want to check if the integer is **in** the set. By the way, the sets you use are wrong (fixed here) and february may have 29 days (not fixed in this solution).

```py
for month in range(1, 13):
    if month in {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}:
        days = 31
    elif month in {4, 6, 9, 11}:
        days = 30
    else :
        days = 28
    print(f"{month:2}: {days}")
```

```
 1: 31
 2: 28
 3: 31
 4: 30
 5: 31
 6: 30
 7: 31
 8: 31
 9: 30
10: 31
11: 30
12: 31
```

#### Calendar approach

Another solution is to use the `calendar` module which fixed the 29 days on february issue.

```py
import calendar


for month in range(1, 13):
    days = calendar.monthrange(2020, month)[1]
    print(f"{month:2}: {days}")
```

```
 1: 31
 2: 29
 3: 31
 4: 30
 5: 31
 6: 30
 7: 31
 8: 31
 9: 30
10: 31
11: 30
12: 31
```